IntelliJ IDEA Navigation with Protocol Buffer files and Kotlin DSL
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and am trying to set it up to work with Kotlin, the Kotlin protobuf DSL, and .protos.
I have a standard project setup with gradle:
// build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.jvm)
    id( "com.google.protobuf") version "0.9.4"
    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(libs.junit.jupiter)
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
    implementation(libs.guava)
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:4.29.1")
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = "org.example.AppKt"
}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

My example proto is:
syntax = "proto3";

package testpkg;

message MyMessage {
  optional string name = 1;
}

In IDEA, I have a source snippet like so:
package org.example

import testpkg.Msg.MyMessage
import testpkg.myMessage

class App {
    val greeting: String
        get() {
            return "Hello World!"
        }
}

fun main() {
    val msg = MyMessage.newBuilder().setName("Test").build()
    val msg2 = myMessage { name = "Test 2" }
    println("Msg $msg, $msg2")
    println(App().greeting)
}

This all works splendid in terms of running and building. IDE tooling seems lacking though:

I can "Find declarations and usages" on the .proto field name, and will find the .setName("Test") call. However the inverse doesn't work - navigating to setName throws me into the generated code, with seemingly no option to get to the .proto file.
The kotlin DSL syntax, myMessage { name = "Test 2" }, doesn't appear to work at all, neither going from .proto to the code, nor navigating to the .proto file.

Question: is this a missing feature, or a setup issue on my side?
